# Instance member 'user' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: firebase, dart

I am trying to create a register function and I am getting this error "Instance member 'user' can't be accessed using static access." for this line
String userId = UserCredential.user!.uid;

[I am uploading error page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QICLp.jpg)

here is the code

````dart
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
Future<bool> register(String email, String password, String username) async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

    
   String userId = UserCredential.user!.uid;
   final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId);
    await userRef.set({
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
    });
    return true;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
      print('Password provided is too weak');
      global.error = "Password provided is too weak";
    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      global.error = "The account already exist for that email.";
      print('The account already exist for that email.');
    }
    return false;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return false;
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I have uploaded the code

Comment: As explained by the error message, `user` is an *instance* member.  You can use it only on a `UserCredential` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the code sample in the documentation on [creating a user with email+password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) and the [`UserCredentials` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) it seems that the proper way to get the newly created user and their UID is:

```
var credentials = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
var user = credentials.user!;
var uid = user.uid;
```